# ASHX delete file after download

Tags: asp.net, .net, ashx

I'm transmitting a file using a generic handler (.ashx).

Then I need to delete the file after it's done transmitting.

```
try{
  context.Response.ClearContent();
  context.Response.ContentType = "text/octet-stream";
  context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
  context.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
  context.Response.End();  
}
finally {
  //File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

When I'm using the finally statement, the file is deleted before the transmit is completed.

How can I handle the Transfer Complete event?

p.s. I can't using global.asax or MVC.

Comment: What happens if the transfer fails and you need to do it again?

Comment: Try to flush the file before the end `context.Response.Flush`

Comment: try with `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instead of `context.Response.End();`